# Polymorphic relationship - what is stored in the type attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism, has-many, polymorphic-associations, belongs-to

Let's say you have a polymorphic relationship like this:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pretty_pictures, as: :imageable
end

class ProductInvoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pretty_pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

And this is your migration for the Picture model:

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pictures do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :imageable, polymorphic: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Let's say you have a @product_invoice with an :id of 1 and you have a @picture that belongs to this product. I know that @picture.imagable_id should equal 1, but what the value stored in @picture.imagable_type be?

- 'ProductInvoice'
- 'ProductInvoices'
- 'product_invoice'
- 'product_invoices'

Answer (score 0):

via G.B in comments

'ProductInvoice'